# Listening for HTTPS Connect request in Chrome Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, proxy

I am trying to use an HTTPS proxy with authentication via my Chrome Extension. Even though I am using `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders` to setup custom headers, the HTTPS proxy won't work.

I suspect this is because Chrome sends a CONNECT request automatically to the proxy without raising an event. The proxy checks for custom authentication headers and in case they are not present, refuses to connect.

Any ideas on how I can listen for the CONNECT request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`webRequest` API is [designed in a way that proxying is transparent to it](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#life_cycle_footnote).

See also the list of headers ignored by `onBeforeSendHeaders` at that link.

Therefore, you cannot influence proxying with `webRequest`.

Comment: Yeah, so it seems. I also found this Chromium thread that says it cannot be done: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=129572

Answer (score 0):

```
  function interceptData() {
        var xhrOverrideScript = document.createElement('script');
        xhrOverrideScript.type = 'text/javascript';
        xhrOverrideScript.innerHTML = `
        function addXMLRequestCallback(callback) {
            var oldSend, i;
            if (XMLHttpRequest.callbacks) {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.push(callback);
            } else {
                XMLHttpRequest.callbacks = [callback];
                oldSend = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send;
                XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send = function () {
                    for (i = 0; i < XMLHttpRequest.callbacks.length; i++) {
                        XMLHttpRequest.callbacks[i](this);
                    }
                    oldSend.apply(this, arguments);
                }
            }
        }

        addXMLRequestCallback(function (a) {
            a.onloadend = (xhr) => {
                if (xhr.currentTarget.responseURL.includes("api.google.com")) {
                console.log(xhr.currentTarget.response);
                }
                if (xhr.currentTarget.responseURL.includes("https://api.google.com")) {  
                console.log(xhr.currentTarget.response);
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
        document.head.prepend(xhrOverrideScript);
      }
      function checkForDOM() {
        if (document.body && document.head) {
          interceptData();
        } else {
          requestIdleCallback(checkForDOM);
        }
      }
      requestIdleCallback(checkForDOM);
```

And add this in manifest.json

```
"run_at": "document_start"
```

makantha that works!